# Android app crashes when mod tries to delete comment of non-member user

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments, android-app, deleted-comments

If a moderator tries to delete a comment of a user that is not a member on the site (because the question was migrated) then the Android app crashes (app version 1.0.77).

The bug can be reproduced consistently.

**Update January 14, 2020:**
I'm now using Android app version 1.0.95 and noticed this bug still/again is present. The app crashes every time I try to delete a comment written by people that are not a member on the site (migrated question). I tried it with 3 different users, all non-members at the time of writing, and get the same behavior every time.

Comment: Please note that the App will not receive bug fixes: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342029/158100

Comment: @rene That's too bad. I like the app. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to hear about that. Unfortunately, the Android app is no longer supported. Please use the responsive web on your mobile device.